# Softinput keyboard hides edit text

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, window-soft-input-mode

i have an activity having edit texts and a date field. Everything works fine if i don't open the date picker dialog fragment. If i open datepicker fragment, when the date picker fragment dismisses, edit texts in the layout appears behind the keyboard. It doesn't move above it in the layout.

Answer (score -1):

Please change input method if you are using some tools like the visor 
otherwise, put the below code in your XML file

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

Comment: already tried this, my actual problem is date picker hides keyboards when the date picker fragment dismiss the adjustPan is not working